# Please help me understand the following sentences

Tags: translation, meaning

> ご来店頂きました様でありがとうございます。宿泊もしています。SAMURAI Inn 
> で。今後とも宜しくお願い申しあげます。18日なら舞妓、小花さんの撮影会していましたよ。

I think I know all the vocab but still I don't quite understand what it means. Especially the particle で in the first sentence.

Does the sentence means something like:

> It seems like you have came to our store, thank you very much. We also do holiday accommodation. SAMURAI Inn. So, I am looking forward to have you in the future. On the 18th, we were having a photo shooting event with maiko, Kohana.

Comment: Mostly alright, but you should check again the 宿泊 part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ご来店頂きました様でありがとうございます

This で is [the te-form of だ](https://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/), which is part of the ようだ construction. The first part just works as the reason for why this person wants to say ありがとうございます (cf. [te-form for reason](https://www.learn-japanese-adventure.com/te-form-cause-reason.html)). If this person had seen you at the store, they would have said simply ご来店頂きましてありがとうございます ("Thank you for visiting") without ようだ. In this case, they did not actually see you but heard from someone that you came, so they inserted ようで.

Similar example:

> - ご迷惑をおかけして申し訳ありません。
>     I am sorry for troubling you.
> - ご迷惑をおかけしたようで申し訳ありません。
>     It seems that (someone) has troubled you, and I am sorry for that.

Your understand of the rest of the text is fine.

Comment: She made a mistake in 「宿泊もしています。」

Comment: This 宿泊もしています means "We also offer accommodations (at Samurai Inn)." (I don't know if "do accommodation" is grammatical as an English sentence...)

Comment: I think the speaker says the guest also stayed at the Inn and not just visited.

Comment: @Chcr Really? I read this as "(If you want to stay in the future,) we also offer accommodations" rather than "(I know) you also stayed at our inn." Note the absence of honorific expressions.

Comment: I noticed the absence of the honorific expression but 宿泊もしています doesn't sound natural if the Inn is saying they also offer 宿泊サービス. I'd say something like 宿泊も（できます）ので、今後とも宜しくお願い申しあげます。Not （しています）. So it appears (at least to me) that upon checking their records, the Inn noticed that the visitor also stayed.

Comment: @Chcr 宿泊もできます is of course natural, too, but that does not mean 宿泊もしています/宿泊もやっています is unnatural. [Example 1](https://deskgram.org/p/1681704759087681358_2327831698), [Example 2](http://kensa.shop/staff_blog/drbrova-dokimin-blog_002).

Comment: @naruto As a native English speaker I don't know if "do accommodation" is grammatical, but I can tell you that it is perfectly natural. e.g. "Do you do accommodation over the Christmas period" would be far more likely to be heard than "Do you offer accommodation ...", but the meanings are identical.

Comment: The truth is I have never went to that inn. I just commented on Facebook under a photo token during a event. The inn could have thought I participated the even and ask me to come stay at their place next time?